# serilog not sending logs to logstash

Tags: .net, logstash, serilog, elk

I'm trying to send logs from c# console application to ELK stack. I followed this  [tutorial](https://blog.romanpavlov.me/logging-serilog-elk/)
step-by-step but it still doesn't work.
This is my logstash.config file:

```
input {
    http {
        #default host 0.0.0.0:8080
        codec => json
    }
}

# Separate the logs
filter {
    split {
        field => "events"
        target => "e"
        remove_field => "events"
    }
}

# Send the logs to Elasticsearch
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index=>"customer-%{+xxxx.ww}"
    }
}
```

I added `RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-input-http` to DOCKERFILE as well,but it just doesn't work.
If I send a post request from logstash container cli,it works and shows up on kibana :
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name:"me"}' http://localhost:8080`
However if I use HttpClient class to post with same parameters,it show up on kibana.
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The sink [Serilog.Sinks.Http](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http) comes with a bunch of sample applications, all of them are listed in the README. One of the examples are demonstrating your specific setup, you can find it [here](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-elastic-stack).